# event.target messing up button area

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, button, meteor

I am using the following code to trigger an event.

```
'click .btn-zoom':function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    var zoomFont = parseInt($('pre code').css('font-size')) + 2;
    if(zoomFont <= 25) {
        $(e.target).parent('code').css('font-size', zoomFont);
//      $('pre code').css('font-size', zoomFont); //Alternative code
    }
},
```

`<button class="btn-zoom"><i class="plus icon"></button>` is the button markup.

The funny thing is, when I use the upper code `$(e.target)....`, the button will only activate when I click the boundaries **within the button** **excluding** the **icon** itself. Simplified, if I click on exactly within the boundaries of the icon, it will NOT activate.

If I use the alternative code mentioned above, it will fire wherever I click within the button.

Is there a way to fix this? I need to use `e.target` because I am planning on having more than one `code` within the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the icon, your `e.target` is:

`<i class="plus icon">`

If you click the button, your `e.target` is:

`<button class="btn-zoom">`

Since you are using `$(e.target).parent`, it is only valid when you click the button because I assume the button's parent is `pre code`, while the icon's parent is actually `<button class="btn-zoom">`.

The reason your alternate code works is because you are directly accessing the `pre code` without relying on the `parent` behavior.

A good way to fix it might be to modify your css for `btn-zoom` to include the icon (using something like the `background` property). That way you are still clicking on the actual button regardless of if you click on the icon or not.

Comment: Ah.. I totally understand now. I should use closest then! I thought `event.target` would be applied to `click element`. Thank you so much!